# Add CSS style to v-html

Tags: html, css, vue.js, sass, vuejs2

I would like to add style to HTML code in a `v-html`. I tried several solutions but nothing functional :(

Here is my code:

Template :

```
<div
  class="para"
  v-html="value" 
/>
```

Script :

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      value : "<h2> TITLE </h2> <p> PARA </p>"
    }
  },
}
```

Style :

```
.para >>> h2 {
  color: blue;
}

.para >>> p {
  color: red;
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I am not too sure if `>>>` is a valid css selector combinator. Did you mean to use `>` ?

Comment: On the other topics, they use >>> each time for the case 
https://medium.com/@brockreece/scoped-styles-with-v-html-c0f6d2dc5d8e

Comment: Did you add scoped attribute to your style tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using `scoped` style without SASS, use the `>>>` combinator this way:

```css
>>> .para > h2 {
  color: blue;
}

>>> .para > p {
  color: red;
}
```

If you're using `scoped` style **with** SASS, use the `::v-deep` combinator:

```css
::v-deep .para > h2 {
  color: blue;
}

::v-deep .para > p {
  color: red;
}
```

Otherwise:

```css
.para > h2 {
  color: blue;
}

.para > p {
  color: red;
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/gb5nr0z6/)

Answer (score 3):

2023 Edit Using Vue 3 + Vite: you will now get this warning when you try to use the solution above:

```
[@vue/compiler-sfc] ::v-deep usage as a combinator has been deprecated. Use :deep(<inner-selector>) instead.
```

So, use this instead

```
:deep(.para > h2) {
  color: blue;
}
:deep(.para > p) {
  color: red;
}
```